# V8 Persistent Handle back To Local

Tags: v8

When converting a persistent function back to a local one, I crash with a memory access violation.

Convert to persistent:

```
Persistent<Function, CopyablePersistentTraits<Function>> funcPersist(isolate, func);
```

Back to local:

```
Persistent<Function, CopyablePersistentTraits<Function>> funcPersist = callback.funcPersist;
Local<Function> func = Local<Function>::New(isolate, funcPersist); // Crash
```

Am I doing this the wrong way?

Comment: The answer is a HandleScope needs to exist on the stack first.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot copy a Persistent (in this case, use the '=' operator) in the recent versions of V8 (ever since it stopped deriving from Handle). Use the constructor (if you create a new one) or Reset (if you change an already existing Persistent).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the constructor to create a new Persistent.

Persistent cb = Persistent(isolate,Local::Cast(args[1]));